# not getting result as expected with fetch_object() in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i m working on a project where i display some images uploaded by user and it is fetched from DB table with `fetch_object()` method, this is my code:

```
<?php 
     $ph1 = $media->fetch_assoc();
     echo "testarray";
     print_r($ph1);
     while ($photo = $media->fetch_object()) { ?>
          <li>
              <div class="gallery-item">
                   <a href="<?= $system->getDomain() ?>/uploads/<?= $photo->path ?>" data-fancybox="gallery">
                      <img src="<?= $system->getDomain() ?>/uploads/<?= $photo->path ?>" alt="User Uploaded Photos" />
                   </a>
               </div>
           </li>
<?php } ?>
```

here `$media` is my result object from query.

the problem with my code is that, while loop starts iterating from 2nd row and skipping 1st. So, my image gallery shows all images except the latest uploaded image to server. I also test that this while loop skipping the 1st is because `$photo` variable is getting all entries except the 1st(or latest), I also test that both `fetch_assoc()` and `fetch_object()` gives the same result i.e. one row less and when i check number of rows returned from query with `$media->num-rows` it returns the exact number of rows that a user uploads. I just cant find why i m not getting first rows ??

Comment: Could you please add your queries? Where does $system came from? Please add your full code.

Comment: _“while loop starts iterating from 2nd row and skipping 1st”_ – you’re blaming the wrong thing here … - _You_ fetched the first record before the loop already, by doing `$ph1 = $media->fetch_assoc();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're fetching the first result and not using it

When you run `fetch_assoc()` you are fetching the first result.

```
$media->fetch_assoc();
```

Once the result has been fetched, it won't be fetched again, so when you loop through `$media` that result is no longer available, nor is it ever used.

---

**Remove the following code and you won't skip the first iteration:**

```
$ph1 = $media->fetch_assoc();
echo "testarray";
print_r($ph1);
```